# How to check if a node has a single child element which is empty?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following code,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var nodes = doc.Element(rootNode)
               .Descendants()
               .Where(n => 
                    (n.Value != "0" 
                    && n.Value != ".00" 
                    && n.Value != "false" 
                    && n.Value != "") 
                    || n.HasElements)
               .Select(n => new 
                { 
                    n.Name, 
                    n.Value, 
                    Level = n.Ancestors().Count() - 1, 
                    n.HasElements 
                });

var output = new StringBuilder();    
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    if (node.HasElements)
    {
        output.AppendLine(new string(' ', node.Level) + node.Name.ToString() + ":");              
    }
else
{
}
```

My problem is that in case my parent node has only one empty child node, I need to insert one extra blank line. I could not figure out how to check if the only child is empty.

I can get the number of descendants using `Descendants = n.Descendants().Count()` But I do not see how can I test if that only child is empty or not.

Comment: for clarification, when you say "child is empty", you mean `string.IsNullOrEmpty(childNode.Value)` would be `true`?

Comment: Also, where would you be doing this/using this check?

Comment: Actually, I would need to check other "empty" types also, say, value = false or 0 or 0.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you need all of the parent nodes who only have one child node, and that child node is empty, from what I understand --

Here's a simple test that accomplishes this: It doesn't use your example specifically but accomplishes the task. If you provide what your XML looks like I can try and modify my example to fit your post, if the below is not easily transplanted into your project :)

(Taken from a console app, but the query that actually gets the nodes should work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xml = @"<root><child><thenode>hello</thenode></child><child><thenode></thenode></child></root>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var parentsWithEmptyChild = doc.Element("root")
        .Descendants() // gets all descendants regardless of level
        .Where(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value)) // find only ones with an empty value
        .Select(d => d.Parent) // Go one level up to parents of elements that have empty value
        .Where(d => d.Elements().Count() == 1); // Of those that are parents take only the ones that just have one element


    parentsWithEmptyChild.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This returns only the 2nd  node, which is the one containing only one empty  node, where empty is assumed to be a value of string.Empty.

Comment: I actually needed to return all non-empty values + all nodes that may have children.

Comment: My XML was like this <dummyParent><Changed><guests/></Changed><CurrentState><guests><someinfo>2000</someinfo></guests></CurrentState></dummyParent>   I needed to produce nice output and I needed one empty line right after Changed to match the output of the original program producing it.

Comment: @Naomi ok that's hilarious, it was a bit difficult to discern what you wanted but had I got that part right, this would be the answer! Since you solved your problem and posted an answer, you can just accept your answer as it is working for you.

Comment: At the end it turned out I didn't need to solve that problem at all. I needed to insert a blank line every time the new top level node begins, not only when the top level had only one and empty child. But it was a good exercise. Thanks again, I think I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this problem myself and this is what I come up with:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

         var nodes = doc.Element(rootNode).Descendants()
             .Where(n => (n.Value != "0" && n.Value != ".00" && n.Value != "false" && n.Value != "") || n.HasElements)
             .Select(n => new { n.Name, n.Value, Level = n.Ancestors().Count() - 1, 
                n.HasElements, Descendants = n.Descendants().Count(), 
                FirstChildValue = n.HasElements?n.Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Value:"" });

         var output = new StringBuilder();

         foreach (var node in nodes)
         {            
            if (node.HasElements)
            {               
               output.AppendLine(new string(' ', node.Level) + node.Name.ToString() + ":");
               if (0 == node.Level && 1 == node.Descendants && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.FirstChildValue))
                  output.AppendLine("");
            }
```

Comment: I think that my own code is not efficient for the problem. I should be able to do the check in the loop instead.